# How to open file in NWJS or Electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, nwjs

Assume there is a notepad like app that has editing functionality .Code mirror library is used for this purpose. Now as the app is NWJS so i don't know how to open any text file in my app directly. just like in other native apps we can select the option in context menu e.g "open with sublime text" .and the file opens in text editor. how can i do that in nwjs app ? any Module there ? Please help me . Thanks

Comment: Which one are you using then, NW.js or Electron?

Comment: i mostly use NW.js but also can use electron ! is there a way of doing that for electron or NW.js ? if yes then how can i do that ? please tell me thanks !

Comment: I think you have to make an installer for your app which tweaks the context menu. It has nothing to do with nw or electron.

Comment: and i think it has nothing to do with installer . and its not about context menu . its about opening file/image in app where it should open, just like native apps .

Comment: e.g if i open an image in an image editor like "Open image in Photoshop"..the image opens in photoshop as it should ! ut if same thing i do with Nw.js app it will open like we Open image in any browser !

Comment: what i want is ..that image or file should open in my app just like native apps with my apps toolbars and other stuff .and image should open in a specified box/area in my app.

Comment: @VadimMacagon how can i do that ? solution please if you know .

Answer (score 0):

The context menu entries you're talking about are created by the OS based on the applications that are registered to handle a particular file type. Electron doesn't provide an API to register an app as a handler for a file type, on Windows you'll need to edit the Windows Registry as described on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127451(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: so its not possible to open a file/image from context menu into our app ? but there are famous Node based compilers e.g atom or brackets which allow to open file from context menu . than how do they do it ?

Comment: I just explained this, you need to register your application to handle the file types you want it to open, then you will get an "Open with MyApp" entry in the context menu, when you click that the OS will launch your app and pass in the filename (on Windows the filename will be provided via `process.argv`, and on macOS via the [`open-file`](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#event-open-file-macos) event).

Comment: ok i understand that ! but i or user have to manually add registry ..but in native and other node apps we don't need to do that ...how ?

Comment: This is exactly what native Windows apps have to do, sometimes the installer modifies the Windows Registry, other times the app itself. You can use `node-ffi` or write a native Node addon/module to allow your Electron app to do this. On macOS it should be sufficient to add some entries to the [app `.plist`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH202-TP9) before shipping.